# array pulling out no results

Tags: php, arrays

```
 public function GetRoomTotalForDay($room, $date = null) {

            if(!isset($date)) {

                $date = date("Y-m-d");

            }

            // This function is going to return the number of shoes processed that day

            // First of all work out which scanner number is required for the room

            $scanner = $this->GetScannerNumber($room);

            // Next generate the SQL

            $sql = "SELECT `scanners.KordNo`, `scanners.BundleNumber`

                    FROM `scanners`

                    WHERE `scanners.Date` = '" . $date . "'

                    AND `scanners.Scanner` IN (";

                foreach($scanner as $x) {

                    $sql .= $x . ",";

                }

            $sql .= "0);";

            // And query the database

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $return[] = $row;

            }

            // It is more complicated for Kettering, Closing & Rushden, we need to filter the list

            if(in_array($room, array(3,4,5))) {

                foreach($return as $x) {

                    $sql = "SELECT `scanners.Scanner`

                            FROM `scanners`

                            WHERE `scanners.KordNo` = " . $x['scanners.KordNo'] . "

                            AND `scanners.BundleNumber` = " . $x['scanner.BundleNumber'] . "

                            ORDER BY `scanners.Date` DESC

                            LIMIT 1,1;";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);



                    // If scanner 7, it's been through bottom stock so need to find previous

                    if($row[0] == 7) {

                        $sql = "SELECT `scanners.Scanner`

                                FROM `scanners`

                                WHERE `scanners.KordNo` = " . $x['scanners.KordNo'] . "

                                AND `scanners.BundleNumber` = " . $x['scanners.BundleNumber'] . "

                                ORDER BY `scanners.Date` DESC

                                LIMIT 2,1;";

                        $result = mysql_query($sql);

                        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                    }



                    if($row[0] == 10 && $room == 3) {

                        $finalReturn[] = $x;

                    } elseif($row[0] == 11 && $room == 4) {

                        $finalReturn[] = $x;

                    } elseif($row[0] == 15 && $room == 5) {

                        $finalReturn[] = $x;

                    }

                }

                $return = $finalReturn;

            }

            // Now we have a list of tickets, we need to query how many pairs are in each ticket

            $total = 0;

            foreach($return as $x) {

                $sql = "SELECT `QtyIssued`

                        FROM `ArchiveBundle`

                        WHERE `ArchiveBundle.KordNo` = '" . $x['scanners.KordNo'] . "'

                        AND `ArchiveBundle.BundleNumber` = '" . $x['scanners.BundleNumber'] . "';";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                $total += $row[0];

            }

            return $total;

        }
```

I have edited the class above which pulls no results. However the original class below pulls results out. Please can someone help.

```
   public function GetRoomTotalForDay($room, $date = null) {

            if(!isset($date)) {

                $date = date("Y-m-d");

            }

            // This function is going to return the number of shoes processed that day

            // First of all work out which scanner number is required for the room

            $scanner = $this->GetScannerNumber($room);

            // Next generate the SQL

            $sql = "SELECT `KordNo`, `BundleNumber`

                    FROM `scanners`

                    WHERE `Date` = '" . $date . "'

                    AND `Scanner` IN (";

                foreach($scanner as $x) {

                    $sql .= $x . ",";

                }

            $sql .= "0);";

            // And query the database

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $return[] = $row;

            }

            // It is more complicated for Kettering, Closing & Rushden, we need to filter the list

            if(in_array($room, array(3,4,5))) {

                foreach($return as $x) {

                    $sql = "SELECT `Scanner`

                            FROM `scanners`

                            WHERE `KordNo` = " . $x['KordNo'] . "

                            AND `BundleNumber` = " . $x['BundleNumber'] . "

                            ORDER BY `Date` DESC

                            LIMIT 1,1;";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);



                    // If scanner 7, it's been through bottom stock so need to find previous

                    if($row[0] == 7) {

                        $sql = "SELECT `Scanner`

                                FROM `scanners`

                                WHERE `KordNo` = " . $x['KordNo'] . "

                                AND `BundleNumber` = " . $x['BundleNumber'] . "

                                ORDER BY `Date` DESC

                                LIMIT 2,1;";

                        $result = mysql_query($sql);

                        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                    }



                    if($row[0] == 10 && $room == 3) {

                        $finalReturn[] = $x;

                    } elseif($row[0] == 11 && $room == 4) {

                        $finalReturn[] = $x;

                    } elseif($row[0] == 15 && $room == 5) {

                        $finalReturn[] = $x;

                    }

                }

                $return = $finalReturn;

            }

            // Now we have a list of tickets, we need to query how many pairs are in each ticket

            $total = 0;

            foreach($return as $x) {

                $sql = "SELECT `QtyIssued`

                        FROM `ArchiveBundle`

                        WHERE `KordNo` = '" . $x['KordNo'] . "'

                        AND `BundleNumber` = '" . $x['BundleNumber'] . "';";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                $total += $row[0];

            }

            return $total;

        }
```

The class above counts the amount of shoes produced. I have had to edit this class so it can exclude certain types of shoes but it does not  seem to pull any results for some reason.

UPDATE.

This is the class scanners. This is what its currently at the moment. I'm fairly new to php and this code was writted by my predecessor.

```
<?php


class CHScanners {



    var $conn;



    // Constructor, connect to the database

    public function __construct() {

        require_once "/var/www/reporting/settings.php";

        define("DAY", 86400);

        if(!$this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD)) die(mysql_error());

        if(!mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn)) die(mysql_error());

    }



    public function ListRoomBundles($room, $date, $dateTo = null) {

        // If dateTo hasn't been set, make it now

        if(!isset($dateTo) or $dateTo == "") {

            $dateTo = $date;

        }

        // Return an array with each bundle number and the quantity for each day

        $scanner = $this->GetScannerNumber($room);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `scanners` WHERE `Scanner` IN (";

            foreach($scanner as $x) {

                $sql .= $x . ",";

            }

        $sql .= "0)

                AND `Date` BETWEEN '" . $date . "' AND '" . $dateTo . "'

                GROUP BY `KordNo`, `BundleNumber`;";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $sql = "SELECT `BundleReference`, `QtyIssued`, `WorksOrder`

                    FROM `ArchiveBundle`

                    WHERE `KordNo` = '" . $row['KordNo'] . "'

                    AND `BundleNumber` = '" . $row['BundleNumber'] . "';";

            $result2 = mysql_query($sql);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

                if($row[0] != "") {

                    $final[] = $row;

                } else {

                    $final[] = array("Can't find bundle number", "N/A");

                }

            }

        }

        return $final;

    }



    public function GetRoomTotalForDay($room, $date = null) {

        if(!isset($date)) {

            $date = date("Y-m-d");

        }

        // This function is going to return the number of shoes processed that day

        // First of all work out which scanner number is required for the room

        $scanner = $this->GetScannerNumber($room);

        // Next generate the SQL

        $sql = "SELECT `scanners.KordNo`, `scanners.BundleNumber`

                FROM `scanners,TWOrder,Stock`

                                    INNER JOIN TWORDER ON `scanners.KordNo` = `TWOrder.KOrdNo`

                                    AND `scanners.Date` = '" . $date . "'

                INNER JOIN Stock ON `TWOrder.Product` = `Stock.ProductCode`

                                    AND `Stock.ProductGroup` NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 650  

                                    AND `scanners.Scanner` IN (

                                    ORDER BY `scanners.KordNo' ASC";

            foreach($scanner as $x) {

                $sql .= $x . ",";

            }

        $sql .= "0);";

        // And query the database

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $return[] = $row;

        }

        // It is more complicated for Kettering, Closing & Rushden, we need to filter the list

        if(in_array($room, array(3,4,5))) {

            foreach($return as $x) {

                $sql = "SELECT `scanners.Scanner`

                        FROM `scanners`

                        WHERE `scanners.KordNo` = " . $x['scanners.KordNo'] . "

                        AND `scanners.BundleNumber` = " . $x['scanners.BundleNumber'] . "

                        ORDER BY `scanners.Date` DESC

                        LIMIT 1,1;";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);



                // If scanner 7, it's been through bottom stock so need to find previous

                if($row[0] == 7) {

                    $sql = "SELECT `scanners.Scanner`

                            FROM `scanners`

                            WHERE `scanners.KordNo` = " . $x['scanners.KordNo'] . "

                            AND `scanners.BundleNumber` = " . $x['scanners.BundleNumber'] . "

                            ORDER BY `Date` DESC

                            LIMIT 2,1;";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                }



                if($row[0] == 10 && $room == 3) {

                    $finalReturn[] = $x;

                } elseif($row[0] == 11 && $room == 4) {

                    $finalReturn[] = $x;

                } elseif($row[0] == 15 && $room == 5) {

                    $finalReturn[] = $x;

                }

            }

            $return = $finalReturn;

        }

        // Now we have a list of tickets, we need to query how many pairs are in each ticket

        $total = 0;

        foreach($return as $x) {

            $sql = "SELECT `QtyIssued`

                    FROM `ArchiveBundle`

                    WHERE `KordNo` = '" . $x['scanners.KordNo'] . "'

                    AND `BundleNumber` = '" . $x['scanners.BundleNumber'] . "';";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

            $total += $row[0];

        }

        return $total;

    }



    // We need a function to select the previous Monday from a given date

    public function GetPreviousMonday($timestamp) {

        if(date("N", $timestamp) == 1) {

            return $timestamp;

        } elseif(in_array(date("N", $timestamp), array(2, 3, 4, 5))) {

            return $timestamp - (date("N", $timestamp)-1)*DAY;

        } elseif(in_array(date("N", $timestamp), array(6, 7))) {

            return $timestamp + (date("N", $timestamp)*(-1)+8)*DAY;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }



    public function GetRoomName($room) {

        // Return the room name from the room number

        switch($room) {

            case 1:

                return "Skin Room";

            case 2:

                return "Clicking Room";

            case 3:

                return "Kettering";

            case 4:

                return "Closing Room";

            case 5:

                return "Rushden";

            case 6:

                return "Assembly Room";

            case 7:

                return "Lasting Room";

            case 8:

                return "Making Room";

            case 9:

                return "Finishing Room";

            case 10:

                return "Shoe Room";

        }

    }



    public function GetDueDateForWorksOrder($worksOrderNumber) {

        $sql = "SELECT `DueDate`

                FROM `TWOrder`

                WHERE `WorksOrderNumber` = '" . $worksOrderNumber . "';";

        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);

        $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);

        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        return $row[0];

    }



    private function GetScannerNumber($room) {

        // Get the room number from the scanner number

        switch($room) {

            case 1:

                $scanner = array(3);

                break;

            case 2:

                $scanner = array(10,11,15);

                break;

            case 3:

                $scanner = array(5);

                break;

            case 4:

                $scanner = array(5);

                break;

            case 5:

                $scanner = array(5);

                break;

            case 6:

                $scanner = array(6);

                break;

            case 7:

                $scanner = array(9);

                break;

            case 8:

                $scanner = array(8);

                break;

            case 9:

                $scanner = array(12);

                break;

            case 10:

                $scanner = array(14);

                break;

            default:

                $scanner = array(0);

                break;

        }

        return $scanner;

    }

}
```

?>

Comment: Have you tried returning the SQL string that is produced, and then tested that string manually?

Comment: I did a var_dump of the array on the first one and it returns an empty array. The sql when run on the sql server matches both classes.

Comment: `foreach($scanner as $x) {$sql .= $x . ",";}` will generate an invalid SQL fragment as the lift of IN values will end in a comma.  Add a 0 to your $scanner array and then use `implode (', ', $scanner);` instead.  Also, the content of the $scanner array is properly escaped, right?

Comment: Oh, and another bit of advice regarding your coding style, your function is way too long and at first glance appears to be running 4 or 5 SQL queries.  Functions this big tend to be a bad idea as they're more difficult to maintain or reuse.  As a general rule of thumb I like to apply, if a function/method is more than a screenful of text in my IDE then that indicates to me that is should be broken down.  Also, DB querying functions should run 1 and only 1 query. Each query embodies an operation and each function in your code should only perform one task.

Comment: i dont understand that. can you demonstrate an example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo - a letter is missing in the last line of this block of code:

```
if(in_array($room, array(3,4,5))) {

            foreach($return as $x) {

                $sql = "SELECT `scanners.Scanner`

                        FROM `scanners`

                        WHERE `scanners.KordNo` = " . $x['scanners.KordNo'] . "

                        AND `scanners.BundleNumber` = " . $x['scanner.BundleNumber'] .
```

Here the array item should be `$x['scanners.BundleNumber']`.

Comment: Using a good editor helps prevent this kind of mistakes. Try Komodo IDE from ActiveState - there is a free version available.